# jquery append var

Tags: jquery, append

If i alert x i can see the value. But from the below code, i can't seem to append the value to #result. What am i doing wrong.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="more">more</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = 'abcde';
var y = x.substring(0,2);    
$('#more').click(function(){
$('#result').append(x);
});        

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your script inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: How can i do without it.

Comment: Your code works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/UAQLN/

Comment: Strange it wasn't working locally due to a space issue. I see it's working on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are to go on this code sample alone then the answer is "You don't have an element with the id 'more' to click on".

That said, you've probably got an overly reduced test case that doesn't show that said element appears after the `<script>` element, so doesn't exist when the script runs and tries to assign the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Oops, your code works. I should've tested it, my bad. +1 to SLaks

---

You need to put your code inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`. Read [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) to find out why.

```
<a href="#" id='more'>More</a>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 'abcde';
    var y = x.substring(0,2);    
    $('#more').click(function(){
    $('#result').append(x);
    });        
});
</script>
```

W/o document ready - http://jsfiddle.net/Z2EjD/ -

```
<a href="#" id="more">More</a>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var addToMore = function addToMore() {
    var x = 'abcde';
    var y = x.substring(0,2);    
    $('#result').append(x);     
}

$("#more").click(addToMore);
</script>
```

That might be able to be improved. If anyone notices something, please comment.

Comment: I think you could make it a function, then call it when you click '#more'. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The example is actually working. it was just not working locally due to a space issue. No need for a function.  +1 for the answer thanks.